# Display static, selectable text in GTK app

Tags: gtk

I am trying to build a small GTK 4 app where the user inputs some data, the program does some computations, and it outputs results in a tabular format.

Currently, I have implemented this using a [GtkGrid](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Grid.html) with [Label](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Label.html) objects showing the results. This works, but a major downside is that the text is not selectable by the user.

**Is there a standard Gtk interface for outputting static, selectable text or tables?** For example, in the Firefox (whose Linux version is based on GTK) settings page, you can use the cursor to select all the explanatory text.

Searching for "text" in the GTK documentation brings me to the [Text Widget Overview](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/section-text-widget.html) page, which is all about multiline text editing. But I don't want my output to be editable—I just want the user to be able to highlight the text and paste it somewhere else if they want.

Answer (score 0):

`GtkLabel` has a "selectable" property which does just that. It's also mentioned in a [separate section of the `GtkLabel` docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Label.html#selectable-labels)

Comment: So is Label the right tool for displaying, say, several paragraphs of text?

Comment: sure, that has always worked fine afaik